# vscode C++ "format document" does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to have vscode be able to just do simple repair of indentation but have not been able to get it to work.  When I select "format document", it does absolutely nothing.  It gives no error and also does not do anything to all the goofy indents.  I have the C++ extension installed, but nothing else. What might be wrong?

Comment: Is the file you're trying to format saved on disk, or is it just a file in buffer? I haven't looked into why it happens, but I've noticed this behavior when trying to format code I just pasted into a new file.

Comment: I saw a comment to that effect elsewhere, but it doesn't help to have it saved.